# Using angular elements inside the same angular project

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements

I'm trying to create a UI kit as reusable web components (using angular elements). I have did a test run to see whether the custom elements that we are developing inside angular project, can be used within that angular project too (In simply, i want to create a documentation like page, for the UI kit + how can i test the UI components that i'm developing - inside the same project).

Here is the link to stackblits
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elements-test-kavinda

I used a separate module called buttons module to develop the ui components, and custom element defining is also done in that module. And i tried the app-component.html to use thosed elemnts - which didn't worked.

Primary-btn-component.html

```
<button>
  <slot name="icon_left" class="icon_left"></slot>
  <slot name="btn_text" class="btn_text"></slot>
  <slot name="icon_right" class="icon_right"></slot>
</button>
```

Code used to define the custom element

```
const btnElem = createCustomElement(PrimaryBtnComponent, { injector: this.injector });
customElements.define('primary-btn', btnElem);
```

Then used that element as below in app-component.html

```
<primary-btn>
  <span slot="btn_text">Button</span>
</primary-btn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix. I used this **Web-Components ES5 adaptor**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.1.3/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
```

Use this in the index.html (inside of the head section)

Answer (score 2):

Create a project without an app

```
ng new my-lib --create-application=false
```

then add a library

```
ng generate library my-lib
```

and then add a demo app that uses the library

```
ng generate application my-lib-demo
```

Detailed steps are in this article.

https://nezhar.com/blog/up-and-running-library-development-with-angular-7/

Comment: Nice approach man :). I fixed my error using web components es5 adaptor. Will ad it as a answer. But this approach is good too, so let's keep it :)